# PHP - How to recognize a date string from the mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, date

The query below will only display the first 5 entries in the DB. I'm looking to get the next 5 based on today's date. The dates are stored in the DB in this format, "2009-10-19'. I don't think it understands the date stored the way it is?

```
//GET TODAYS DATE
$now = date('Y-m-d');

//GET EVENTS
$sql17 = "SELECT * FROM approved WHERE 'date_begin' > '$now' LIMIT 5";
$result17 = $link3->query($sql17);

if ($result17->num_rows > 0) {
while($row17 = $result17->fetch_assoc()) {

$originalDate = $row17["date_begin"];
$newDate = date("M-d-Y", strtotime($originalDate));

echo $row17["requiredeventname"].' - '.$newDate.', '.$row17["requiredcity"].' '.$row17["state"].' - FIND OUT MORE<br>';

}
} else {
echo "Not Found";
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: are you looking to use this as a column or string literal? `WHERE 'date_begin'`. If it's a column, remove the quotes. MySQL should be throwing you an error for it.

Comment: mysql  is the database name, just trying to echo it out

Comment: removing the quotes fixed it. Thank you. I thought for sure I had tried it both ways. I usually do.

Comment: You're welcome. There was a duplicate, for which I closed the question with. *Cheers*